# Is it possible to instantiate same spring-boot app twice with different ports?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to instantiate same spring boot app twice with different ports using the embedded tomcat so these two instances consumes one another rest api. the goal is to simulate two independent programs with same logic as two players.

I have tried the following:

```
        SpringApplicationBuilder playerOne = new SpringApplicationBuilder(GameApplication.class)
                .properties("server.port:" + "8080", "app.name:" + "Player1", "spring.jmx.enable:false");

        SpringApplicationBuilder playerTwo = new SpringApplicationBuilder(GameApplication.class)
                .properties("server.port:" + "8081", "app.name:" + "Player2", "spring.jmx.enable:false");

        ConfigurableApplicationContext run1 = playerOne.run();
        ConfigurableApplicationContext run2 = playerTwo.run();
```

I got javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

How is it possible to achieve that?
shouldn't it initiate two different servers?

Comment: Even if it started correctly, how would `playerOne` know how to communicate with `playerTwo` when `playerOne` doesn't know which port `playerTwo` is listening on? It seems there should be one instance, and two connected clients.

Comment: You could run them in two separated JVMs.

Answer (score 5):

run the jar and give the port as an input argument..

then you can start two applications with two known ports.

```
java -jar myServer.jar --server.port=8080

java -jar myServer.jar --server.port=8081
```

Comment: yes!  This is exactly what I was suggesting at the end of my answer.  This is the right way to do what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to run into a lot of problems with what you are trying to do.  I don't think Spring was designed to allow two independent Spring apps in the same process.

You are running into the first of what will probably be many collisions between these two apps.  You are getting "javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException" because Spring has a global notion of a JMX management bean registry.  When a Spring app launches, it registers a bunch of things with this service under specific names.  You're getting this error when the second copy of your app tries to register something to the registry that the first app has already registered using the same name.

The app itself is registered this way, under the name "SpringApplication". When I run my Spring app, this is the first thing that is registered.  My guess is that your "app" is failing the second time it tries to register this name with JMX.

If you really have to have the code broken up this way, why not put the two apps in their own builds and run them separately?  Or if they're the same exact app, just run two copies, as @Toerktumlare suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run

$ env SERVER_PORT=8001 mvn spring-boot:run

$ env SERVER_PORT=8002 mvn spring-boot:run
```

Answer (score -1):

Add server.port=0 to your application.properties. It will allocate port dynamically.

Comment: I don't think this is going to fix the error the OP reported.  That error has nothing to do with a port conflict

Comment: Yes, agree. I think two JVM is enough.